# Would burning of around 200 kg of animal fat in a tunnel cause an explosion?

Tags: chemistry-in-fiction, fats

As shown in the movie [Ironclad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ironclad_(film)), they burnt a group of fat pigs together, under a tunnel, beneath the fort base and it resulted in a massive explosion.

From chemistry's perspective, and considering the tunnel environment — less oxygen, less space for energy to dissipate,  would this really cause an explosion so massive that it will dismantle the structure above the tunnel? Or would there  be no explosion, just burning?

Apologies for cruelty involved in the question.